# How to trigger Material UI Select in Cypress

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, cypress

I am trying to trigger a MUI Select using Cypress but I cannot get it to work.

I have read the MUI SelectInput source and it is clear they are triggering on "mousedown" event. I have profiled a click and seen that this is true. However, calling `cy.find(input).trigger('mousedown', { force: true })` doesn't trigger the popup, nor does `cy.find('label').trigger('mousedown', { force: true })`, nor does grabbing any of the containing `div` elements and triggering mousedown on them.

If I go to the MUI example page:
https://material-ui.com/components/selects/
and I inspect the DOM there and look at the elements, none of them have an onmousedown handler, and grabbing them as globals and calling `temp<n>.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown'))` doesn't trigger the popup to open. So I cannot figure out where the mousedown handler is being hooked.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In our Cypress tests, we use `findByText` (from Cypress Testing Library)  and do `cy.findByText("Text of the Select label or current selected value").click().findByText("Text of option we want to select").click()`.

Comment: If it can help anyone, here is a workaround inspired from [this thread](https://bleepcoder.com/fr/cypress/529358399/cy-click-doesnt-select-element-in-custom-dropdown-component) to select the first element in the dropdown using the keyboard :
`cy.get('div.MuiSelect-root').first().type('{downarrow}{enter}')`

Answer (score 7):

For Cypress to fill out a Material-UI React `Select` component, this worked for me:

```js
cy.get('#fooID')
  .parent()
  .click()
  .get('ul > li[data-value="FooBar"]')
  .click();
```

Replacing:

- `Foo` with your MUI Select component `Id`
- `FooBar` with the text you want selected in your dropdown bar.

This [post](https://medium.com/@kevpkra/testing-material-ui-components-with-cypress-and-the-react-testing-library-349bedb12ccf) helped point me in the right direction.

In a Material-UI React `Select` component the ID of the form label *is wrapped/controlled by an outer div.*  So `.get('#fooID')` grabs the inner label by ID, `.parent().click()` clicks the *root component div* to reveal the dropdown, and `.get('ul > li[data-value="FooBar"]').click()` finds & clicks the correct item in the dropdown bar.

Answer (score 3):

[Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements) recommends to assign a unique `data-cy` prop to the elements that Cypress should interact with, so you should do that for both the select box and its options.

See the example below (assuming you're still using Material-UI v4):

**The Select component:**

```js
<TextField
  select
  data-cy={`input-fruits`}
  defaultValue=''
>
  {
    [`apple`,`banana`,`orange`].map((fruit, index) => (
      <MenuItem
        key={`item-${index}`}
        value={fruit}
        data-cy={`select-option-${fruit}`}
      >
        {fruit}
      </MenuItem>
    ))
  }
</TextField>
```

**The Cypress test:**

```js
it("should change value of select box", () => {
  /** Confirm that the select box is empty by default */
  cy.get(`[data-cy = "input-fruits"]`).should(`have.value`, ``);

  /** Click on the select box, then on the option */
  cy.get(`[data-cy = "input-fruits"]`).click();
  cy.get(`[data-cy = "select-option-orange"]`).click();

  /** Assert the new value of the select box */
  cy.get(`[data-cy = "input-fruits"]`).should(`have.value`, `orange`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create select using TextField with name="myselect"

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#select

```js
<TextField
  name="myselect"
  select
  label="Select"
  value={currency}
  onChange={handleChange}
  helperText="Please select your currency"
>
  {currencies.map((option) => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.label}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

where options:

```
const currencies = [
  {
    value: 'USD',
    label: '$',
  },
  {
    value: 'EUR',
    label: '€',
  },
];
```

Use can select option via only label:

```
cy.get('[name="myselect"]').parent().click();
cy.get('[id="menu-myselect"] li[role="option"]').contains("€").click();
```

Dropdown gets autogenerated *id* based on TextField *name* with prefix *menu-*

Answer (score 0):

this one works for me, imagine the default text is `Organization` on your select and you want to choose `SUN` from dropdown

```
cy.findByText('Organization').type('SUN{enter}');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  it("should change check items per page and change it", () => {
    const select = '[data-testid="pagination-select"]'
    cy.get(select).children('input[aria-hidden="true"]').should('have.value', '10');
  
    /** Click on the select box, then on the option */
    cy.get(select).click();
    cy.get('ul[role="listbox"]').children('li[data-value="8"]').click()

    cy.get(select).children('input[aria-hidden="true"]').should('have.value', '8');
    cy.get('[data-testid="deputy-list"]').children().its('length').should('be.equal', 8)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

for me on MUI, worked this one:

**cy.contains('[role="option"]', 'City').click();**

So first we find a element with text "City" and with role Option and then click it