# Cypress dropdown select for Mui (Material UI) highlighted option

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, material-ui, cypress

How do I cypress select Mui (Material ui) dropdown options?

Expecting something easy to understand please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you are trying to do, but the testing of a MUI listbox is fairly straight forward IMO.

Here is a similar scenario [How to test React Material UI "Select" with Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71244231/how-to-test-react-material-ui-select-with-cypress).

The poster has given enough detail for a reproducible example, so you can test on your own machine and confirm it fits with your own problem.

This is the annotated test code suggested, which should work for you:

```js
cy.get('#any-make-dropdown').click()           // open the list
cy.contains('chevroletMalibu').click()         // select an option
cy.get('#any-make-dropdown')
  .should('contain', 'chevroletMalibu')        // confirm the new value
```